# Where is hadoop-ec2-env.sh in the Hadoop packages?

Tags: apache2, amazon-ec2, hadoop

I'm unable to locate the file `hadoop-ec2-env.sh`.

I've downloaded and intalled hadoop_1.0.4-1_x86_64.deb from http://mirror.olnevhost.net/pub/apache/hadoop/common/stable/

This is the most recent stable version.

I would like to run hadoop on EC2.

I'm following a tutorial that says: [Edit all relevant variables in src/contrib/ec2/bin/hadoop-ec2-env.sh.](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonEC2)

Where is `hadoop-ec2-env.sh`?

Comment: I think those instructions are really out of date, I've checked the debs they publish and I can't find that file anywhere.

Comment: @JorgeCastro thank you very much for checking. could you recommend to me what i can do to to "edit relevant variables..." which file should i be touching?

Answer (score 1):

> This is a partial answer that needs more investigation by someone who's deployed Hadoop before.

It seems that those instructions are out of date, I tried both 1.0.x and 1.1.x debs and neither have the file `src/contrib/ec2/bin/hadoop-ec2-env.sh`.

However there is a `/etc/default/hadoop-env.sh` file that has environment variables in it, no clue if this is the right place to put the AWS credentials though.

Comment: thank you very much for checking. there are a few other places, as well: /etc/default/hadoop-env.sh
/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
/etc/profile.d/hadoop-env.sh

Comment: so i am at a lose, i dont know which one to touch!