# should i install the .deb or .tar.gz?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, deb, tar, hadoop

Please pardon the elementary question.

I'm going through [this](http://rodrigodsousa.blogspot.com/2012/03/hadoop-amazon-ec2-updated-tutorial.html) tutorial.

I would like to install hadoop on vm ubuntu 64 bit.

I would like to know whether I should be downloading the .deb file or the tar.gz file from [here](http://www.bizdirusa.com/mirrors/apache/hadoop/core/stable/)?

What is the difference between these two types of files? Does ubuntu care which one?

Comment: @Aditya perhaps you can assist with this http://askubuntu.com/questions/286092/installing-and-configuring-hadoop-on-ubuntu

Comment: Have a look at this answer too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/144433/how-to-install-hadoop

Answer (score 4):

.tar.gz is usually source code of that. So download it if you know what you are doing . Else simple download and install using .deb package

Comment: thank you very much..and a related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/286092/installing-and-configuring-hadoop-on-ubuntu

Comment: There is more to the answer then a .deb being "simpler", it has to do with package management.

Comment: This answer is too telegraphic, and was not helpful to me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following is easiest:

`dpkg -i packagename.deb`

A tar.gz is often source code that would need to be compiled, and that isn't always very easy (particularly when it comes to figuring out what options are required or desired).